# BottomNavigation with NavController doesn't retrieve/parse arguments correctly

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, navigationcontroller

I'm having some trouble retrieving arguments in a Fragment using BottomNavigation and NavigationUI. I retrieve null value after navigating to an addOrderFragment(picture). I'm out of ideas why this doesn't work.

Navigation layout: http://prntscr.com/pf9tl1 
Activity layout: http://prntscr.com/pf9u4q  
Activity layout has a NavHost fragment in which all other layouts are inflated and navigation in this segment works fine.

**Main activity**

```
  UID = getIntent().getStringExtra("UID");
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("UID", UID);
    //navigation
    controller = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.fragment_container);
    controller.setGraph(R.navigation.navigation_mainmenu, args);
    controller.navigate(R.id.mainMenuFragment, args);
    bottomNav = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNav, controller);
```

**Retrieving UID from another fragment after being navigated to it**

```
 controller = Navigation.findNavController(view);
        try {
            UID = getArguments().getString("UID"); <---gets null 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Crashlytics.logException(e);
        }
```

Comment: If your UID is global to your activity, why are you using Fragment arguments at all? Fragments can call `requireActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("UID")` itself

Comment: @ianhanniballake I'm not sure why tbh. It works now, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your UID is global to your activity,  you shouldn't be using Fragment arguments at all. Fragments can call `requireActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("UID")` to retrieve extras from the Activity.